# UISearchBar Dismiss Method

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

For a UISearchBar with UISearchDisplayController, when the searchfield is clicked, the keyboard appears and an overlay shows over the tableview.  When cancel is clicked

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

is called.

I am wondering if there is a method called when the overlay is clicked.  It does dismiss the keyboard and go back to the tableview.  Basically I want to make clicking this overlay run the same method as when cancel is clicked.  Any ideas?  I checked the Apple Docs and couldn't find anything other than the cancel button method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can subclass UISearchDisplayController and call this cancel method from [touchesBegan method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

   ```
   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   ```
2. You can assign the [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the overlayView.

Answer (score 1):

*CANCEL : just [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO]; and implement it inside touchesBegan like ToMfromTO's answer.

Comment: But do you know what method is called when you just click away from the uisearchbar without clicking cancel?  It does dismiss the searchbar and keyboard, but I need it to run another method as well